# How can I pass a table field name as dynamically to function?

Tags: php, field

I have been trying yo pass the field name and table name as dynamically in function like below format:

```
       function GetTBL($TBL, $FIELDS) 
       {
           ........
           $query = "SELECT $FIELDS FROM $TBL ";
           .....
           ......
        }
```

but I don't have any idea for how to call that function and how to use it? Please help me.

Comment: What table exactly? Can you post more details?

Comment: are you asking class based or simple function?

Comment: @phillip i want to change the $FIELDS & $TBL value as dynamically depending on the functionality,(i want to reuse that code) Thank u so much for your response & gave for your valuable time! Now i got clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

Your function

```
    function GetTBL($table,$fields = "*",$limit=10){

        $sql = "SELECT $fields FROM $table  LIMIT $limit";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        return $result;

}
```

At the time of calling this function you have to pass parameter

example

```
$table="mytable";
$fields=" myname,mysurname ";
$result=GetTBL($table,$fields); // other parameters take  default value if you not pass value
```

You can make this function more reusable by passing other parameter for condition , orderby etc according to your requirement.

Comment: Thanks a lot yadav, actually i got a little confuse, Now i have cleared

Comment: @DRAJI thats good keep coding :)

Comment: @DRAJI you should also try class based coding for re usability purpose

Comment: ya, i have used that function which is in 'users' class inside of users.class.php file, i called that function from edit-profile.php file for putting that DB coloumn value into their corresponding input field.but i have repeated that select query in my project, Now it works well with that reusable code, Thank you so much yadav!

Answer (score 0):

if your table is called "mytable" and field "myfield"

Call it like this

```
$results = GetTBL($mytable, $myfield);
```

Comment: how to assign $myfield value? if my field values are id, name, email, $myfield="id,name,email"; am i right?

Comment: Thank u so much for your immediate reply

Comment: You could do e.g `$id=5; $email='draji@mail.com';` and so on.  I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve but that's how you assign variables in PHP.